# Highlight street view supported area

Tags: google-maps, highlight, google-street-view

I'm developing an Android app using google maps android sdk. As I want to show some streetview supported area on map, like whenever you drag pegman icon of google map, the highlighted area which will be shown to indicate these area support street view.

Is it possible to do this via android google map sdk ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [StreetViewCoverageLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#StreetViewCoverageLayer), and you should do something like:

```
var svLayer = new google.maps.StreetViewCoverageLayer();
svLayer.setMap(map);
```

I also uploaded a sample on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ch3raeh/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this method works with api v3, right ? Is it posible to do this via android maps sdk v2